# Customization through Coding in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, code

I am new to magento & I don't know anything about magento 1.x. I am working on magento 2. Can anyone suggest me some resources where can I find the links for Coding in magento?

I have already referred to official site but I want to understand the coding part

All the built in classes, functions etc.

Comment: No. I want to understand coding of magento.& I have already referrred that " Can anyone suggest more technical resources for Magento 2?"  but that didn't help me.

Comment: i would recommend you, first understand the structure & follow the tutorials (as so many are available, search how to create module for magento2)..
even I dont know Magento 1.x but working on magento 2.x, so try to create very basic module, there is nothing big in that...
Hope you have basic Idea of MVC & OOPs and obviously PHP.

Comment: The official site contains a "coding part": http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html - did you find that? if so, what are you looking for instead? A complete API reference based on phpdoc or similar does not exist yet, but is planned: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1011 - that being said, I don't think that would be very helpful for a beginner. Too much information and too little "how to do X"

Answer (score 2):

There's no Magento 2 Codex like there is for WordPress.

However, you can find the official documentation at the following link: http://devdocs.magento.com/

If you are learning Magento 2 I highly recommend the **[Magento U Fundamentals course](https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development)** that I took myself and helped me a lot understanding the software.

On top of that I recommend the **[Alan Storm articles](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2)** that explain with deep investigations the concepts of Magento 2.

Try to get your hands on one of those books, it'll help you as well

[image]

Finally I suggest you use **Magento StackExchange and [Magento Forums](https://community.magento.com/)** as much as possible as you will get a lot of help from the community if you face any issue.

Comment: I have this link with me. But i need to know the available methods ,classes like for creating table, for loading template etc.

Comment: @user2431224 there's no such website available for Magento 2. Using an IDE like PHPStorm might help you for that

Comment: Magento U Fundamentals course is too costly.IS there anything free ebooks?

Comment: @user2431224 not that I'm aware of